# Можно ли как то 3 блока оставить flex-start, а один сделать flex-end?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.box
{
    width: 31px;
    height: 33px;
    background: red;
    margin: 1px;
}

.prostokat
{   
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:500px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prostokat">
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, свойство align-self для дочернего элемента.

```css
.box
{
    width: 31px;
    height: 33px;
    background: red;
    margin: 1px;
}

.box:last-child{
  align-self:flex-end
}

.prostokat
{   
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:500px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prostokat">
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Нет, но можно между ними вставить блок, для раздвижки.

```css
.box
{
    width: 31px;
    height: 33px;
    background: red;
    margin: 1px;
}

.prostokat
{   
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:500px;
    height: 1000px;
}

.extender {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="prostokat">
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
           <div class='extender'></div>
           <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Тут, похоже, про выравнивание по поперечной оси